# Why were my "not an answer" flags on answers that consist only of "yes" declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, answer-quality

I flagged many "Yes" answers and *most* of those flags got declined (some of them, however, got approved and one *was* declined but deleted).

> [image]

Do you consider "Yes" (sometimes linked to somewhere) to be an answer? Why were my flags declined?

- [Does Weblogic 9.x support the 2.4 Servlet standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103271/does-weblogic-9-x-support-the-2-4-servlet-standard/103296#103296)
- [Can I use Struts2 without Spring IoC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783982/can-i-use-struts2-without-spring-ioc/4783993#4783993)
- [Sample code for insert and delete row iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335149/sample-code-for-insert-and-delete-row-iphone/3335166#3335166)
- [How to rotate table-headline in Latex table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519692/how-to-rotate-table-headline-in-latex-table/2519755#2519755)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025128/use-of-rel-canonical-and-upper-case-in-url/2025143#2025143
- [Can I run VS 2008 and VS 2010 on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262125/can-i-run-vs-2008-and-vs-2010-on-the-same-computer/2262137#2262137)
- [Is this class a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601521/is-this-class-a-pojo/4601546#4601546)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137123/is-it-possible-to-master-c-sharp-and-net-framework-to-a-point-that-nothing-is-n/3137193#3137193 (lol, "yes" links to Jon Skeet ;D)

Comment: @Payeli I searched for them in this way and flagged some ;-)

Comment: Please don't go searching for stuff to flag.

Comment: @BoltClock Trying to lessen the work load? I agree that people that don't know what is an answer and what isn't shouldn't be searching for answers to flag. But people who do, should help out if they can. Also, it doesn't take too many declined flags to get suspended from flagging..

Comment: @Vote to Close: It's not about trying to lessen the workload. It's about handling more immediate and/or pressing problems rather than finding old and otherwise harmless answers ("Yes." is a crappy answer but it is still an answer in its own right, is not actively harmful and so does not merit speedy deletion, and particularly not *in bulk*).

Comment: @BoltClock approach like this is probably why some believe that **[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)**

Comment: @VotetoClose - In addition to what BoltClock said, removing accepted answers that actually answer the question does not make the Internet a better place. It's one of the reasons I'm still opposed to outright removing link-based answers that have proven to be useful. I think we're losing sight of the forest for the trees.

Comment: @BradLarson I too think that link only answers can be useful. Problem is that the linked ressources sometimes vanish over the years. A way to archive linked ressources would be nice.

Comment: @nicael - no!!!!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They **are** answers.

They are bad, low quality, terrible answers, but they **are** answers.

Downvote and flag as low quality.

---

Reserve the "not an answer" to things that are clearly not attempting to answer the question.

---

Also see:

[How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

Comment: Flag as low-qua? Ok, understood. Thought that I should flag as not an answer. Sorry.

Comment: note there's no option to flag VLQ if an "answer" has positive score

Comment: True enough, @gnat, though the chances of a single word answer to have a positive score is trending to 0 as time goes by.

Comment: It is, of course, rare. However sometimes [single-word answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3137193/2963652) have a score of a little bit more than 0 ;-)

Comment: Btw. quite often the underlying question is bad as well if a simple "Yes" sufficiently solves it. For example "Can I.." questions when simple trying out would give an answer already.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Why flag as low quality? I thought the purpose of low quality flags were to flag answers that have _severe formatting or content problems_ and are _unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed_ where the emphasis is "to be removed". This isn't really the case for these. They're low quality in the sense that they don't offer much but they **are answering the question**. If we start flagging/deleting questions for this reason, I think a lot of potentially helpful answers could be lost. Have I misunderstood this flag reason?

Comment: @CarrieKendall I think in the case where "yes" answers the question, then the *question* is probably low quality and should be closed/deleted.

Comment: @CarrieKendall - there are a lot of answers that are _trying_ to answer the question but fall short or are completely off or are answering something else - these are all _answers_ but are of low quality and yes, should be deleted from the site.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure that is accurately conveyed in your answer, but maybe it was just me that got confused :). One more question: Completely off meaning they aren't at all related to the question or completely off meaning they are incorrect?

Comment: @Carry - either, both... take your pick. If not related, they are not really answering the question so should be deleted, if they are related but are incorrect, they should be deleted (in particular if they are actively harming - say the answer contains sqli).

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes - not always, not often, but sometimes - "Yes" is the correct answer.

So the standard advice for flagging still applies: **do not flag stuff based on a simple pattern-match** - we have a perfectly good regular expression engine that can do this. If you're not gonna evaluate the posts you're flagging *in context*, then there's a really good chance they're all gonna be declined en masse, because all you're doing is effectively saying,

> Hey! Moderator! Yeah, you, the guy who's already handled hundreds of flags today! Here are dozens of posts that may or may not be bad - I'm entirely too lazy to actually evaluate them myself, so you should do that for me.
>
> Regards, -the Human RegEx Engine

Needless to say, this will not endear you to anyone.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think you'd be amazed since it probably is still a very low percentage of all answers. But I don't agree with the thought that a little bit of link only answers are okay. Just like I don't think anyone would agree that a little bit of spam is ok.

Comment: My concern is whether or not answers answer the question. If you can't be bothered to determine that before flagging, you're just creating more work for someone else. The presence of a link does not automatically damn an answer.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're doing a bit more than simple pattern matching, @Vote. Which, sadly, wasn't the case in the scenario we're discussing here.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Comment: Flagging your answer as low-qua, as Oded ♦ suggested ;-)

Comment: Flagged as _"it is not an answer"_, because this does not attempt to answer the complete question.

Comment: @Cerbrus it does indeed answer the whole question. It is not a correct answer, but an answer. Because if you consider Yes as answer, then it is self explanatory why his flags got declined ;)

Comment: Eeh, that actually makes sense, @Theolodis... It seems I can't retract flags, though :-/

Comment: Don't worry, this answer isn't all that serious. Oded explained it quite well.

Comment: Yea, I know ;-)

Comment: I like it though, it is so simple and does yet answer all aspects of the question ;D

Comment: This is my favourite answer on the whole Stack Exchange site :-)